# How to disable gnome "Blank screen"

Tags: linux, gnome, screensaver, blank-screen, xscreensaver

I am using SUSE Linux with gnome-2. My screensaver runs for 5 minutes and the screen goes blank after that. I want to disable the "Blank screen".

I tried the following commands:

```
$ setterm -blank 0
$ setterm -powerdown 0
```

I also added the following lines to etc/X11/xorg.conf under ServerFlags section

```
Option          "BlankTime"     "4"
Option          "StandbyTime"   "0"
Option          "SuspendTime"   "0"
Option          "OffTime"       "5"
```

But this did not work.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think `setterm` is the wrong command.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a poke around in the GUI config app (System Settings > Advanced > Power Management) and check your power options for your current profile. Sounds like 'Dim display when idle for x min' is turned on somewhere.

Comment: thanks.. but I have to do this in a script. I can't use GUI

Comment: Why can't you change the settings via the GUI, out of interest?

Comment: For GNOME3, changing the setting for one user does not appear to change the setting for the system. It leads to trouble on some machines, like needing to wait for the user to login so the ethernet connection comes up. Otherwise the machine stays in some low power state after reboot and SSH does not work.